# Custom hook alwas restore initial state value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to adapt a custom hook I found in some tutorials on the internet. I'm trying to change some things in order to practice creating custom hooks. So please be gentle with my question :) I'm quite a newbie in this subject.

Here is my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import * as translations from "../translations";

const useTranslation = () => {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("fr");
  const [fallbackLanguage, setFallbackLanguage] = useState("fr");
 
 const translate = (key) => {

    const keys = key.split(".");

    return (
      getNestedTranslation(language, keys) ??
      getNestedTranslation(fallbackLanguage, keys) ??
      key
    );
  };

  return {
    language,
    setLanguage,
    fallbackLanguage,
    setFallbackLanguage,
    t: translate,
  };
}

const getNestedTranslation = (language, keys) => {
  keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
    return obj?.[key];
  }, translations[language]);
};
```

The problem here is that when I try to change the language (using `setLanguage("en")` in a button par example), the language always comes back to "fr". In other words, when I click on that button and I console.log the language, it does change to "en" but immediatly changes to "fr".

Is the component rerendering and so the state is reinitializing? Or is there something I  am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can see one problem — you define `getNestedTranslation` _after_ it’s used in `useTranslation`.

Comment: How did you use the custom hooks in your component? Show the code

Comment: If `useState` resets to initial value it means component is recreated(unmount+mount) by a parent. Hard to say what is the reason, but definitely not because of code in this component.